# Send signal to process and wait x seconds for it to disappear

Tags: linux, bash

I would think this is a **common idiom** in Linux world so my question is if there's some build-in functionality for it ?

Something like:

Args:

```
$PID  - the process to send signal to
$SIGNAL_NAME   - the signal to send to the process
$WAIT_TIME    - number of seconds to wait for $PID to disappear
```

The command I'm looking for would send the process $PID the $SIGNAL_NAME and then wait synchronously for $WAIT_TIME until the $PID process disappears. Command would have some proper exit code of course.

I can write such script quite easily. I would just expect it to be a common requirement? Perhaps a shell build-in ?

Answer (score 0):

Arghh

I was hoping for an option on the `kill` command or something that would do this trick for me.

The best solution I've found so far is:

```
kill -$SIGNAL_NAME $PID; timeout ${WAIT_TIME}s tail -f /dev/null --pid $PID
```

which works fine assuming that the `tail` command supports the `--pid` option.
However, this is a prime example of one of (many) Linux command constructs that requires a significant amount of time and investigation to understand what it really
does. In 1 months time I will have forgotten why the above works. :-(

The `killall --wait` command seems to be pretty close to a build-in solution to the problem except that it doesn't accept PID as an argument.